# unable to display multiple highchart graphs in angular?

Tags: jquery, angular, highcharts

i am using highcharts for displaying graphs in angular. In my scenario i need to display multiple graphs with random data and previous graph should not reflect when new data is passing for new graph..
i am using this below code

```
    runData = [320, 330,333,341,346,351];
    var create = function(id){
    $(document.body).append("<div id='c"+id.toString()+"'></div>");
    $('#c'+id.toString()).highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) 
                   + '<br/>' +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: this.runData
        }]
    });
   }

create(1);
runData = [220, 320,333,321,326,251];
create('b');
runData = [120, 310,313,121,126,151];
create('c');
```

It is showing error while running, like

```
     ERROR TypeError: 
     jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__(...).highcharts is not a 
      function
      at create (chatbox.component.ts:62)
```

Comment: Seems like Highcharts are not registered as a jQuery module in your case. Could you try with a non-jQuery initialization of a chart - [`Highcharts.chart()`](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart)?